# Why is my GDB batch mode exit status always 0?

Tags: gdb

The [GDB docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options) say:

> **`-batch`**
>
> Run in batch mode. Exit with status **`0`** after processing all the command files specified with ‘**`-x`**’ ... Exit with nonzero status if an error occurs in executing the gdb commands in the command files.

But even when there are errors, I get an exit status of zero. For example:

```
$ cat gdbscript 
foo
$ gdb -batch -x gdbscript 
gdbscript:1: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "foo".  Try "help".
$ echo $?
0
```

The GDB program status is correct if I use `quit 1`, for example, in the script.

Why is this happening to me? Is there a way around it? I'm trying to flash a remote target, and I'd really like GDB to exit with error status if it fails.

My GDB version, should it happen to be important:

> GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 7.8.0.20150604-cvs

Comment: It's gdb bug. See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13000, https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18488.

Comment: Well that's disappointing. I am just about to test my own patch, but maybe I'll take the recommended one from there, instead.

Comment: @ks1322 - feel free to make that an answer and I'll throw some internet hugs your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening to me? Is there a way around it?

It is known gdb [Bug 13000](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13000). You can apply [experimental patch](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=8343) from Bug 13000 and rebuild gdb which may work for you.

Comment: I can confirm that this is fixed in versions 9 and 10 of `arm-none-eabi`.